# Squarespace redirect through code injection leads to blinking of editor

Tags: javascript, html, code-injection, squarespace

when I add the following code to a page's  Tag in Squarespace the editor starts blinking:

`<script> window.location.href = "https://google.com" </script>`

This is just an example. In the end I want to link to my discord Oauth2 login page. See the video below to get an idea of what happens:

[video](https://fiverr-res.cloudinary.com/video/upload/t_fiverr_hd/v1/video-secured-attachments/messaging_message/attachment/3f4fbd61f6908737ae0b20e1d0fb0f57-1681164571295/Screen%20Recording%202023-04-10%20at%203.07.03%20PM?__cld_token__=exp=1681329382%7Ehmac=86bd1f98b58a264c6a679ddcbda3bb148dc9cc6367d9955328b8a0694c134e31)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.